# AsyncTask status is always running

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-play-services

Hi I'm try to get Google Play Service Ads Id in AsyncTask.
I read Android AsyncTask API documentation and many stackoverflow Answer. I want to get Ads Id first and will start other process.
Accordingly, I made AdIdAsyncTask for getting Ads Id in BackgroundThread and invoke in my MainActivity. But My AsyncTask status is always RUNNING. 
What's Wrong?

**MainActivity and AdIdAsyncTask**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DummyActivity";
    private final long MEDIA_ID = 292929L;
    private final String ACCESS_KEY = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";

    private String adId = null;

    private AdContext adContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdIdAsyncTask task = new AdIdAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "task.getStatus=" + task.getStatus());

        if (task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
            // do work
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public class AdIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo = null;
            try {
                idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fetch Google Ads is failed. message=" + e.getMessage());
            }

            String advertisingId = null;
            try {
                advertisingId = idInfo.getId();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "adId is null. message=" + e.getMessage());
            }

            adId = advertisingId;
            cancel(true);

            Log.i(TAG, "adId=" + advertisingId + ", isCancelled=" + isCancelled());

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

            super.onCancelled();
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {

            super.onCancelled(aVoid);
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
D/DummyActivity: task.getStatus=RUNNING
D/DummyActivity: doInBackground
I/DummyActivity: adId=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, isCancelled=true
I/DummyActivity: onCancelled
I/DummyActivity: onCancelled
```

**SdkVersion**

```
compileSdkVersion 25
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: _Async_ means _asynchronous_. The `execute()` call will return immediately, and the rest of the code in `onCreate()` will continue to run while the `AsyncTask` does its work on a separate thread.

Comment: so, how can i revise my code for getting ads id and executing other process?

Comment: why you are checking task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
in onCreate()?

you just started AsyncTask in your onCreate and you are checking status immediatly, Its not relevant there

Comment: @byrage you can override AsyncTask.onPostExecute() to get your id and do your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can force close the AsyncTask
Please use the following code in yout AsyncTask with condition and call it in your activity where you want to stop, it will stop your asynk task running

```
/**
 * Check if asynctask is running, if still running cancel it.
 */
public void forceCancel(){
    if (getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
        cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: append forceCancel() method in my AsyncTask class and call method in MainActivity, but AsyncTask status is still RUNNING.

Comment: @byrage
you have to call forceCancel()  method outside AsyncTask wherever you want to stop

Comment: @byrage
forceCancel() is not override method in AsyncTask so you have to forceCancel() method  outside AsyncTask